# Minecraft spigot-1.16.5: event.getInventory() does not work

Tags: plugins, minecraft

I created a custom Inventory and I want to disable player to taking item out of it but it seems doesn't work. And there is no error on the console.
[My "Inventory" code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLvUl.png)

[And disable taking item
note: these send messange just to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwM6B.png)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to implement InventoryHolder,

What you can do is remember which inventory you opened for the player.

```
public enum InventoryType {
    MENU_1,MENU_2,MENU_3
}

public static Map<UUID,InventoryType> openedInventory = new HashMap<>();

@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent event) {
    Player player = (Player)event.getWhoClicked();
    InventoryType type = openedInventory.get(player.getUniqueId());
    if (type == null)
        return;
    switch (type) {
    case MENU_1:
        //TODO Handel
        break;
    case MENU_2:
        //TODO Handel
        break;
    case MENU_2:
        //TODO Handel
        break;
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onInventoryClose(InventoryCloseEvent event) {
    openedInventory.remove(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
}

@EventHandler
public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
    openedInventory.remove(event.getPlayer().getUniqueId());
}
```

Then, when you open an inventory, you need to openedInventory as folows:

```
openedInventory.put(player.getUniqueId(), InventoryType.MENU_1);
player.openInventory(inv);
```

If there is something you don't understand in my solution, feel free to ask, I used here some technics and classes that I don't know if you know.